# \hrule screws up minipage right indent

Tags: horizontal-alignment, rules

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[
  top=0.75in, bottom=0.75in, left=0.75in, right=0.75in,
  textheight=8.75in
]{geometry}


\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}


\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.4\linewidth}
{\LARGE\textsc{My Name}}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\linewidth}
\begin{flushright}
\footnotesize\texttt{myemail@abc.edu}
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}
\smallskip
\hrule
\bigskip

{\textsc{ABC University}}

\end{document}
```

My code is above... if I remove the `\hrule` the email aligns correct to the right; however as soon as I add it it screws up. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: I get essentially the same result in both cases.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "right indent" in the question's title. Have you tried inserting a `\noindent` right before the minipage?

Answer (score 3):

Actually you do not need a `minipage` here.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[
  top=0.75in, bottom=0.75in, left=0.75in, right=0.75in,
  textheight=8.75in
]{geometry}


\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}


\begin{document}
{\LARGE\textsc{My Name}}
\hfill
\footnotesize\texttt{myemail@abc.edu}
\smallskip
\hrule
\bigskip
{\textsc{ABC University}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In case you want to retain your `minipage`s, you should make their width almost half of the `textwidth` as `\begin{minipage}[b]{0.495\linewidth}`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[
  top=0.75in, bottom=0.75in, left=0.75in, right=0.75in,
  textheight=8.75in
]{geometry}


\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}


\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.495\linewidth}
{\LARGE\textsc{My Name}}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.495\linewidth}
\begin{flushright}
\footnotesize\texttt{myemail@abc.edu}
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}%
\smallskip
\hrule
\bigskip
{\textsc{ABC University}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you can issue a `\hfill` inbetween the minipages like

```
\begin{minipage}{0.4\linewidth}
{\LARGE\textsc{My Name}}
\end{minipage}\hfill % ,----here
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\linewidth}
\begin{flushright}
\footnotesize\texttt{myemail@abc.edu}
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}%
\smallskip
\hrule
\bigskip
{\textsc{ABC University}}
```

to get the same effect as mentioned in the comment by @egreg.

Comment: It doesn't matter how wide the two minipages are, as long as they contain the required text. Rather put `\hfil` between them and add `\par` after the second one. However, the `minipage` free solution is better, albeit a bit faulty with respect to line spacing.

Comment: I followed that (without using the minipage), however it doesn't flush perfectly with the right hand side. (i.e. the email ends before the line ends). However if I add a \linebreak it flushes perfectly, however then that would add too much vertical spacing. Why is this? How can I fix this? Thanks!!

Comment: @user1358251: Add `%` immediately after your email to align it flush with the right margin.

Comment: thanks that fixed it!! can you give me an explanation why tho?